# Zoom in some parts of the plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering if this is possible to zoom in some parts of the plot in ggplot. Like in this example I would like to have an axes in the first row set to 10 not to 30 but at the same time leave it at 20 in the fourth row.

Is that possible?

Best,
Magda

This is my data:

```
type   WT     length DB replicate   membr_perc
PC PC [32:1]     32  1        4C  0.004568968
PC PC [32:2]     32  2        4C  0.311537413
PC PC [34:1]     34  1        4C  0.025441318
PC PC [34:2]     34  2        4C  0.941114699
PC PC [34:3]     34  3        4C 19.964341010
PC PC [34:4]     34  4        4C  9.062968566
PC PC [36:2]     36  2        4C  4.996974342
PC PC [36:3]     36  3        4C  2.608663261
PC PC [36:4]     36  4        4C  1.160078509
PE PE [32:1]     32  1        4C  0.013162015
PE PE [34:1]     34  1        4C  0.230250161
PE PE [34:2]     34  2        4C  2.404199267
PE PE [36:1]     36  1        4C  0.074131338
PE PE [36:2]     36  2        4C 13.969398670
PE PE [36:3]     36  3        4C  6.286180052
PG PG [32:1]     32  1        4C  0.003806120
PG PG [34:1]     34  1        4C  0.323901833
PG PG [34:2]     34  2        4C  1.542359703
PG PG [36:2]     36  2        4C 28.309575620
PG PG [36:3]     36  3        4C  0.979650738
CL CL [64:0]     64  0        4C  0.000000000
CL CL [68:2]     68  2        4C  0.221536513
CL CL [68:4]     68  4        4C  0.098994606
CL CL [70:4]     70  4        4C  0.247770428
CL CL [72:2]     72  2        4C  1.383800362
DI       DIP      1  9        4C  2.737254136
mD      mDIP      1  9        4C  2.098340358
PC PC [32:1]     32  1        4C  0.006469708
PC PC [32:2]     32  2        4C  0.313912208
PC PC [34:1]     34  1        4C  0.020691554
PC PC [34:2]     34  2        4C  0.929850519
PC PC [34:3]     34  3        4C 20.494618610
PC PC [34:4]     34  4        4C  9.503915694
PC PC [36:2]     36  2        4C  5.179105140
PC PC [36:3]     36  3        4C  2.628755762
PC PC [36:4]     36  4        4C  1.209026327
PE PE [32:1]     32  1        4C  0.007488329
PE PE [34:1]     34  1        4C  0.203643654
PE PE [34:2]     34  2        4C  1.964658280
PE PE [36:1]     36  1        4C  0.078437649
PE PE [36:2]     36  2        4C 12.433119640
PE PE [36:3]     36  3        4C  5.593785510
PG PG [32:1]     32  1        4C  0.009837235
PG PG [34:1]     34  1        4C  0.321859375
PG PG [34:2]     34  2        4C  1.545486068
PG PG [36:2]     36  2        4C 30.073080650
PG PG [36:3]     36  3        4C  0.968242053
CL CL [64:0]     64  0        4C  0.000578315
CL CL [68:2]     68  2        4C  0.210845062
CL CL [68:4]     68  4        4C  0.098191065
CL CL [70:4]     70  4        4C  0.246968672
CL CL [72:2]     72  2        4C  1.437064277
DI       DIP      1  9        4C  2.536628933
mD      mDIP      1  9        4C  1.983739708
PC PC [32:1]     32  1        4C  0.007225555
PC PC [32:2]     32  2        4C  0.304025973
PC PC [34:1]     34  1        4C  0.045072818
PC PC [34:2]     34  2        4C  0.912889329
PC PC [34:3]     34  3        4C 19.360961880
PC PC [34:4]     34  4        4C  9.106571206
PC PC [36:2]     36  2        4C  5.101734042
PC PC [36:3]     36  3        4C  2.462570737
PC PC [36:4]     36  4        4C  1.130462511
PE PE [32:1]     32  1        4C  0.017576666
PE PE [34:1]     34  1        4C  0.255338461
PE PE [34:2]     34  2        4C  2.358026232
PE PE [36:1]     36  1        4C  0.120381355
PE PE [36:2]     36  2        4C 13.599001840
PE PE [36:3]     36  3        4C  5.801035213
PG PG [32:1]     32  1        4C  0.004101141
PG PG [34:1]     34  1        4C  0.346119276
PG PG [34:2]     34  2        4C  1.512986594
PG PG [36:2]     36  2        4C 28.671750760
PG PG [36:3]     36  3        4C  0.938071076
CL CL [64:0]     64  0        4C  0.000635345
CL CL [68:2]     68  2        4C  0.237560539
CL CL [68:4]     68  4        4C  0.122620736
CL CL [70:4]     70  4        4C  0.334470518
CL CL [72:2]     72  2        4C  1.529412629
DI       DIP      1  9        4C  3.171852488
mD      mDIP      1  9        4C  2.547545077
PC PC [32:1]     32  1       13C  0.237395528
PC PC [32:2]     32  2       13C  0.134681434
PC PC [34:1]     34  1       13C  0.064136083
PC PC [34:2]     34  2       13C  1.087151057
PC PC [34:3]     34  3       13C  8.325405224
PC PC [34:4]     34  4       13C  2.379120532
PC PC [36:2]     36  2       13C  7.939279055
PC PC [36:3]     36  3       13C  2.402261775
PC PC [36:4]     36  4       13C  0.493759599
PE PE [32:1]     32  1       13C  0.031819118
PE PE [34:1]     34  1       13C  0.488762018
PE PE [34:2]     34  2       13C  4.511385095
PE PE [36:1]     36  1       13C  0.265345829
PE PE [36:2]     36  2       13C 32.547493400
PE PE [36:3]     36  3       13C  9.010573736
PG PG [32:1]     32  1       13C  0.002001495
PG PG [34:1]     34  1       13C  0.190935979
PG PG [34:2]     34  2       13C  0.804344486
PG PG [36:2]     36  2       13C 14.920456650
PG PG [36:3]     36  3       13C  0.238707192
CL CL [64:0]     64  0       13C  0.001144995
CL CL [68:2]     68  2       13C  0.410726550
CL CL [68:4]     68  4       13C  0.108661125
CL CL [70:4]     70  4       13C  0.401729495
CL CL [72:2]     72  2       13C  3.349649409
DI       DIP      1  9       13C  4.776221495
mD      mDIP      1  9       13C  4.876851644
PC PC [32:1]     32  1       13C  0.218097809
PC PC [32:2]     32  2       13C  0.102566839
PC PC [34:1]     34  1       13C  0.028618787
PC PC [34:2]     34  2       13C  0.831784332
PC PC [34:3]     34  3       13C  6.728083275
PC PC [34:4]     34  4       13C  1.949321892
PC PC [36:2]     36  2       13C  5.927665949
PC PC [36:3]     36  3       13C  1.808646353
PC PC [36:4]     36  4       13C  0.372919272
PE PE [32:1]     32  1       13C  0.022006628
PE PE [34:1]     34  1       13C  0.370147732
PE PE [34:2]     34  2       13C  3.254514812
PE PE [36:1]     36  1       13C  0.239641835
PE PE [36:2]     36  2       13C 25.374396380
PE PE [36:3]     36  3       13C  6.928308393
PG PG [32:1]     32  1       13C  0.007652133
PG PG [34:1]     34  1       13C  0.388524011
PG PG [34:2]     34  2       13C  1.731323933
PG PG [36:2]     36  2       13C 33.204884010
PG PG [36:3]     36  3       13C  0.486696579
CL CL [64:0]     64  0       13C  0.000854878
CL CL [68:2]     68  2       13C  0.317566463
CL CL [68:4]     68  4       13C  0.076091557
CL CL [70:4]     70  4       13C  0.265579988
CL CL [72:2]     72  2       13C  2.697381593
DI       DIP      1  9       13C  3.082738094
mD      mDIP      1  9       13C  3.583986477
PC PC [32:1]     32  1       13C  0.205793279
PC PC [32:2]     32  2       13C  0.092040068
PC PC [34:1]     34  1       13C  0.073067505
PC PC [34:2]     34  2       13C  0.853554543
PC PC [34:3]     34  3       13C  6.221964264
PC PC [34:4]     34  4       13C  1.673981019
PC PC [36:2]     36  2       13C  6.220126884
PC PC [36:3]     36  3       13C  1.828839542
PC PC [36:4]     36  4       13C  0.366984971
PE PE [32:1]     32  1       13C  0.039866413
PE PE [34:1]     34  1       13C  0.382074873
PE PE [34:2]     34  2       13C  3.505874903
PE PE [36:1]     36  1       13C  0.207274668
PE PE [36:2]     36  2       13C 24.268192390
PE PE [36:3]     36  3       13C  6.817662081
PG PG [32:1]     32  1       13C  0.010718190
PG PG [34:1]     34  1       13C  0.387591051
PG PG [34:2]     34  2       13C  1.789596755
PG PG [36:2]     36  2       13C 32.429419490
PG PG [36:3]     36  3       13C  0.501206419
CL CL [64:0]     64  0       13C  0.001387258
CL CL [68:2]     68  2       13C  0.347318908
CL CL [68:4]     68  4       13C  0.089433716
CL CL [70:4]     70  4       13C  0.310210558
CL CL [72:2]     72  2       13C  2.831744905
DI       DIP      1  9       13C  4.492477691
mD      mDIP      1  9       13C  4.051597653
PC PC [32:1]     32  1       20C  0.197620250
PC PC [32:2]     32  2       20C  0.151006936
PC PC [34:1]     34  1       20C  0.107256117
PC PC [34:2]     34  2       20C  0.979207564
```

This is the code I used to plot the data:

```
ggplot(data=wt_temp,aes(x=replicate,y=membr_perc,color=factor(length)))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(facets="type ~ DB")
```

An this is the plot:
[image: Plot]

Comment: `facet_grid(facets="type ~ DB", scales="free")`?

Comment: wow, thanks! that works! And if i would like to zoom in the first row/ first column plot? Is that possible?

Comment: You can't (easily) arbitrarily zoom the individual facets.

Comment: you can zoom in if you wrap your plot into `ggplotly(your_ggplot)` from library **plotly**. I don't know if that is what you want but nevertheless it adds bit of interactivity and ability to zoom in.

Comment: Thank you! That looks awesome,  but it is not working very well in RStudio.